# is it possible to index character strings pulled from an external .txt file?

Tags: string, matlab, indexing

I'm in a basic MATLAB college course, and need some help with my code.

theres an external .txt file with names in it, with corresponding numbers assigned to each name. my goal is to place all the first names, last names, and numbers into arrays, find the lowest number in the 'number' array, get the corresponding indexer number, and print the first and last name related with that number.

the text file reads 25 different names and numbers
(i.e.:

Bob
Smith
17
Jane
Doe
23
Bill
Johnson
13

...etc...)

here is my general code so far:

```
1  clear
2
3  clc
4
5
6  fid1=fopen('facedata.txt','rt');
7 
8  for index = 1:1:25
9     firstn(index) = fgetl(fid1);
10    lastn(index) = fgetl(fid1);
11    number(index) = fscanf(fid1,'%f');
12 end
13
14 [distmin,I] = min(dist);
15 fprintf('%5.4f %10s %10.0f', distmin, firstn(I), I);
```

My hope is for the code to run through, get matlab to recognize '13' as the lowest number, and print 'bill johnson' to the screen, but if I run the code, matlab says there are errors

`Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.' @ line 9.`

and

`Index exceeds matrix dimensions.' @ the firstn**(I)** in line 15.`

any ideas?? i know this is crazy long, but any help would be appreciated! :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question earlier today, but here's what I found if anyone is interested:

you have to index a line of string by using curly brackets instead of straight ones.

i.e.:

```
for index = 1:1:25
firstname{index} = fgetl(fid1);
end

fprintf('%10s', firstn{index});
```

fprintf will print whichever number index is supplied.

thanks anyway kavka :]

Answer (score 0):

The command `fgetl` means read a line from the text file.  Therefore your code is reading 2x25 = 50 lines of text. How do you know that your file has this many lines in it? You should read a new line, process it, and repeat until you reach the end of the file:

```
fid = fopen('fgetl.m');
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
  disp(tline)
  tline = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```

However, this would not do what you want.  You should rather use `fscanf` to read data in the format you want.  You want to read two consecutive strings (first name, last name) and an integer number. So you can use

```
A = fscanf(fid, '%s %s %d', [3 inf]);
```

to read three items at a time and repeat until the end of the file.